# Python: iterate over unicode characters in string

Tags: python, unicode

I would like to iterate over each character in a Unicode string and I'm doing so as such:

```
import unicodedata
import json

words = ['\\u05d5\\u05b7\\u05d9\\u05b0\\u05d3\\u05b7\\u05d1\\u05bc\\u05b5\\u05a3\\u05e8', '\\u05d9\\u05b0\\u05d4\\u05b9\\u05d5\\u05b8\\u0594\\u05d4', '\\u05d0\\u05b6\\u05dc\\u05be\\u05de\\u05b9\\u05e9\\u05c1\\u05b6\\u05a5\\u05d4', '\\u05d5\\u05b0\\u05d0\\u05b6\\u05bd\\u05dc\\u05be\\u05d0\\u05b7\\u05d4\\u05b2\\u05e8\\u05b9\\u0596\\u05df', '\\u05dc\\u05b5\\u05d0\\u05de\\u05b9\\u05bd\\u05e8\\u05c3']
for word in words:
    print(word)
    print(type(word))
    for idx, char in enumerate(word):
        char_name = unicodedata.name(char)
        print(char_name + ": " + char + " : " + json.dumps(char)) # comment out
```

But the output comes out as such:

```
REVERSE SOLIDUS: \ : "\\"
LATIN SMALL LETTER U: u : "u"
DIGIT ZERO: 0 : "0"
DIGIT FIVE: 5 : "5"
LATIN SMALL LETTER D: d : "d"
DIGIT FIVE: 5 : "5"
REVERSE SOLIDUS: \ : "\\"
LATIN SMALL LETTER U: u : "u"
```

How can I iterate over the Unicode characters inside a string?

I imagine I need to convert `\\u` to `\u` but don't know how to do that:

```
print(word.replace('\\u', '\u'))
                                  ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \uXXXX escape
```

Comment: I'm not though. Please read the question more carefully.

Comment: This is not at all the output I am getting when I run your code: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU/LCsIwELznK5acWpRSKUUt@CdCiU2kEbIJeYB@fWy2BWsOm5nZ2Zf7xNlil7M2zvoICfVkpZIiCrZJr2CRbfo4zcIHuAG/p7aXfYmPM@Er4ZZwt9NPhCeK5BeUVRfOntaDlu8jlK6gERQmo7yIqvqbVw8M6BU2ojBq2WC3aVOkqiTrzei8xlj97AfgA/Dlo0kLg5WW2xqZjAtreZ3zFw "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: You have a string whose contents look like a Python `str` literal, not the `str` value `'וַיְדַבֵּ֣ר'`.

Comment: Can you check to make sure the code you've pasted is _exactly_ the code you are running? Otherwise, please copy-paste the code that is giving this output into one block so we can test/debug it.

Comment: @hyper-neutrino my bad - please see revised code above

Comment: That would be because you're escaping the backslashes. If you want the unicode characters, only put one backslash, so it actually becomes the unicode character escape code.

Comment: I understand, but how do I do that? I don't know how to replace it. Please see code above in my attempt to replace it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either type the word list correctly without double backsplashes:

```py
words = ['\u05d5\u05b7\u05d9\u05b0\u05d3\u05b7\u05d1\u05bc\u05b5\u05a3\u05e8', '\u05d9\u05b0\u05d4\u05b9\u05d5\u05b8\u0594\u05d4', '\u05d0\u05b6\u05dc\u05be\u05de\u05b9\u05e9\u05c1\u05b6\u05a5\u05d4', '\u05d5\u05b0\u05d0\u05b6\u05bd\u05dc\u05be\u05d0\u05b7\u05d4\u05b2\u05e8\u05b9\u0596\u05df', '\u05dc\u05b5\u05d0\u05de\u05b9\u05bd\u05e8\u05c3']
print(words)
```

Or convert the list using `.decode('unicode_escape')`, but you must `.encode()` to a byte string first.  Since the original strings are all ASCII characters, you can use nearly any standard encoding for the conversion to bytes, but `'ascii'` is the most explicit:

```py
words = ['\\u05d5\\u05b7\\u05d9\\u05b0\\u05d3\\u05b7\\u05d1\\u05bc\\u05b5\\u05a3\\u05e8', '\\u05d9\\u05b0\\u05d4\\u05b9\\u05d5\\u05b8\\u0594\\u05d4', '\\u05d0\\u05b6\\u05dc\\u05be\\u05de\\u05b9\\u05e9\\u05c1\\u05b6\\u05a5\\u05d4', '\\u05d5\\u05b0\\u05d0\\u05b6\\u05bd\\u05dc\\u05be\\u05d0\\u05b7\\u05d4\\u05b2\\u05e8\\u05b9\\u0596\\u05df', '\\u05dc\\u05b5\\u05d0\\u05de\\u05b9\\u05bd\\u05e8\\u05c3']
words = [word.encode('ascii').decode('unicode_escape') for word in words]
print(words)
```

Both result in:

```py
['וַיְדַבֵּ֣ר', 'יְהֹוָ֔ה', 'אֶל־מֹשֶׁ֥ה', 'וְאֶֽל־אַהֲרֹ֖ן', 'לֵאמֹֽר׃']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the split() command in Python to break up your sting into a list. You can then iterate over the elements inside the list. You could do this al follows:

```
string = "\\u05d5\\u05b7\\u05d9\\u05b0\\u05d3\\u05b7\\u05d1\\u05bc\\u05b5\\u05a3\\u05e8"

splitted = string.split("\\")
targetlist = []
for s in splitted[1:]:
    targetlist.append(f"\\{s}")
print(targetlist)
```

This yields:

```
['\\u05d5', '\\u05b7', '\\u05d9', '\\u05b0', '\\u05d3', '\\u05b7', '\\u05d1', '\\u05bc', '\\u05b5', '\\u05a3', '\\u05e8']
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the words need to encoded and decoded to escape the backslash:

```
words = [word.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode_escape') for word in verse_unicode.split()]
```